# Free disk space on a network drive in Delphi

Tags: delphi, diskspace

I am making a program for A2 Computing which exports a lot of data. My HDD allocation on the local network is about 50 MB, so it's a good candidate to test the "no disk space" error.

Currently when the program runs out of space it crashes mid-export with I/O Error 112. I would like to warn ahead of time if the file might exceed available space. I know how big the file will be (24.8 bytes per record, on average), so all I need to do is find out how much space is free.

As I am working on a network drive, with a file path like `\\qmcsan1\Cxxxxx$\filename.csv`, how do I use functions like `DiskFree` to calculate available space? Any such function also needs to handle local drives like `C:/`.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: See RRUZ answer in this SO thread [how-to-get-total-disk-space-of-windows-drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383598/delphi-how-to-get-total-disk-space-of-windows-drive). Uses WMI and works on remote computers.

Comment: @LU RD, WMI abuse is really crappy approach. I foresee the case when user authorized to use the share fails WMI privilege check.

Comment: @LU RD If the user is able to write to the volume then presumably they can just use Win32 API to get free space rather than needing heavy weight WMI.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I agree, using the Win32 API is the best approach here. The purpose of the link I gave, was to have an alternative and a cross-link to a similar question.

Comment: @user539484, `..WMI abuse is really crappy approach`, Do you  now which very critical process in your system like probably the antivirus which is protecting your computer right now uses the WMI?, Use the WMI to get the size of a remote (or shared) resource is totally valid.

Comment: `...I foresee the case when user authorized to use the share fails WMI privilege check`, yes this can happen because the access to a shared resource is not the same required by the WMI , so the oppositte case can happen too, you can get info about a remote resource even if not is shared using the WMI. Finally obviously that exist tasks where the WinAPI is the right tool (like access to local resources) and another where the WMI is a better option.

Comment: @PRUZ, i didnt understand a thing. How antivirus advocates **for** WMI? Meanwhile, WMI has been designed for administrative VBScript task, bringing it to High Level Languages is almost never qualifies as *right tool*. Look at the answer below, it is consistent. Finally, i believe you got my point with authorization, now do not ignore it.

Comment: Here are a comparison [wmi-vs-windows-apis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713389/wmi-vs-windows-apis).

Comment: @user539484, You will be surprised, how many critical system services and aplications uses the WMI. About your comment `...bringing it to High Level Languages is almost never qualifies as right tool` The WMI exposes several interfaces, the scripting side (Microsoft WMIScripting Library) used by vbscript or others scripting languages is just a wrapper over a very rich COM set of classes [(COM API for WMI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389276%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) what can used from languages like C++ and Delphi.

Comment: @user539484 Also if you want more information about ths subject read this [Accesing the WMI from Delphi and Free Pascal via COM](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/accesing-the-wmi-from-delphi-and-fpc-via-com-without-late-binding-or-wbemscripting_tlb/)

Comment: @RRUZ, no, i dont want a blog. What you are oftenly proposing here are **scripting** IDispatch bindings. Not a right tool. Also, i'm perfectly aware of WMIScripting startup timing.

Comment: @user539484, WMI Scripting Libray <> COM API for WMI.

Comment: @user Are you making a point about early binding vs late binding? I think there may be an interesting discussion somewhere in all this, but it's getting a bit too close to a rant.

Comment: @David Heffernan, not too interesting, look at the typical RRUZ's WMI boilerplate, you'll see what scripting approach brings to us. My points are listed above, despite of **four** (ridiculous!) votes for WMI advocacy on UNC query none of the problems went away. Metarant: yeah, people are usualy ranting when seeing rant in the comments.

Comment: @RRUZ - > *"how many critical system services and aplications uses the WMI"* > I find it a bit odd that critical system services would depend on WMI, yet the service can even be disabled for whatever reason.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, Yes any service (like the WMI) can be disabled by any reason, but if this service (WMI) is stopped many apps and services will stop of working in your system.  Just for name a few services and apps which depends of the WMI . Windows Firewall / Internet connection sharing (ICS), IPHelper , Windows Security Center, VMWare , Some Sql Server Services, etc.

Comment: @user539484, if don't like my answers based in the WMI, is fine to me. But will be nice which you propose alternative solutions to problems like start/list/kill remote process, list hardware info in local or remote machines, receive events of files and devices in local and remote machines, etc. Also most of my answers is based in the WMI scripting version just to make the code more brief and easy to understand.

Comment: @RRUZ, *make the code more brief and easy to understand* – i fail to see how degrading most of datatypes to `OleVariant` makes code cleaner and easier to understand. From your blog i came to conslusion what these codes is merely machine-generated from the template. Also, your list of "critical" system services is quite random and appears to be simply dumped from `services` MMC snap-in.

Comment: @RRUZ, *propose alternative solutions to problems* – thanks for the tasks, but none of those will even fit into comment format, in particular, i believe PsExec-like functionality achieved via RPC support (which is really critical service in Windows)

Comment: @user539484, `..degrading most of datatypes to OleVariant` really ?, do you know a way to deal with COM without use any variants? `..what these codes is merely machine-generated from the template` yes this is true that template was developed by me. `...system services is quite random and appears to be simply dumped from services MMC snap-in` yes is random because comes to my mind in his moment. You can easily test this, checking if a process or service has load the wbemcomm.dll and/or wbemprox.dll. Finally this will be my last comment . See you.

Comment: @RRUZ, *do you know a way to deal with COM without use any variants?* – of course I do, thats called an early binding. *that template was developed by me* – so those codes are easy to understand for YOU, this not automagically makes them easy to everyone else. *Finally this will be my last comment . See you.* - surrender accepted :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One easy approach is to call the [`GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function.

Unfortunately this function is mis-declared in the Delphi Windows unit, at least it is in XE2. But there is a version declared in SysUtils which is correct. Make sure you use that version!

```
program FreeDiskSpace;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  SysUtils;

const
  Folder = 'C:\';

var
  FreeAvailable, TotalSpace: Int64;

begin
  if SysUtils.GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(PChar(Folder), FreeAvailable, TotalSpace, nil) then begin
    Writeln(TotalSpace div (1024*1024*1024), 'GB total');
    Writeln(FreeAvailable div (1024*1024*1024), 'GB free');
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for this - looks like it would work. Only problem is, I'm a complete noob in Delphi. I'm trying `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(PWideChar(save_dialog.FileName), @freespace, nil, nil)`, but it's never storing any number in `freespace`. Any idea why?

Comment: You are probably on an ANSI version of Delphi. See my update. Make the changes described in my final paragraph and call it like this: `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(PChar(save_dialog.FileName), @freespace, nil, nil)`. Or @TLama could be correct too.

Comment: ...or just use `PChar` and it will work in all Delphi versions.

Comment: @Smasher No it won't. You need to get the correct import, either the `A` or the `W`. It would be so much easier if the declaration in Windows.pas was correct!!!

Comment: @David: For me there's only one `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` in SysUtils...what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Smasher That one is fine. It's the one in Windows.pas that is broken. I'll update the answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for this - I've just got back to college to work on my project. However, the disk free function is telling me I have 1,000 GB free. Would be nice, but I don't... I'm guessing it's finding the capacity of the whole network drive and not just my allocation, is there a way to make it find my allocation instead?

Comment: I'm using `SysUtils.GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(PChar(Folder), FreeAvailable, TotalSpace, nil)` with a path like `\\qmcsan1\\Cxxxxx$\`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Unfortunately I'm using a very restricted computer. I'll try later with a USB stick; but other than that, I have no access to local volumes.

Comment: @ThomasO This is probably an issue with your local IT setup as much as anything. Very hard for us to help without being able to reproduce that setup.